# programmatically get domain name only in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Can anyone tell me how can I get the **domain name only** in sharepoint? i would like to add a user to a group and there I have to specify the domain name. I don't not want to hardcode it.

"domain\sp_user1"

any help will be very much appreciated.